# Why does passing a variable to a lambda in Kotlin works?

Tags: lambda, kotlin

Suppose I have high order function that accepts a lambda as a parameter like this:

```
fun getNum(op: () -> Int) = op()
```

And a function that returns a number:

```
fun getTen() = 10
```

In the main function I can call the `getNum()` function like this

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    val x = 50
    val a = getNum(::getTen)    // a == 10
    val b = getNum{x}           // this works and b == 50
}
```

Why does passing a varibale instead of lambda works? Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Kotlin, the last or the single expression in a lambda [is the return value](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#returning-a-value-from-a-lambda-expression).

In the `getNum { x }` expression, `{ x }` is a lambda with a single expression `x` in it, which is thus considered the return value, so when the lambda is invoked, it only evaluates `x` captured in the [closure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#closures) and returns its value back to `getNum`.

The `getNum(::getTen)` call is, in turn, the usage of a [callable reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#callable-references) (it is distinguishable by the `::` sign), which can be passed as a value of the functional type `() -> Int` just the same as if it would be `getNum { getTen() }`.

See: [Lambda Expressions and Anonymous Functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions) in the language reference.